Distribution of the marked points on the components of a stable n-pointed curve of genus zero
Let $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ be the fine moduli space of stable n-pointed curves of genus $g=0$. Let $[(D_{0},p_1,...,p_n)] \in \overline{M}_{0,n}$. Suppose that each component of $D_0$ contains at least one of the n-points $p_i$ on it. Why is it possible to choose a neighborhood $U\subset \overline{M}_{0,n}$ of $[(D_{0},p_1,...,p_n)]$ such that, for every $[D,q_1,...,q_n] \in U$, the marked points $p_1,…,p_n​$ intersect each component of $D$?

Openness of ampleness for $\mathcal{O}_D(\underline{p}_1+\dots +\underline{p}_n)$.
